# Mapping a string value to a custom type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I am new to typescript and was wondering if there was a way to map a string value to a custom type when calling functions with templates?

for example:

`object.method<TypeMapper['CustomType']>([...])`

where in this case CustomType may be a custom interface such as:

```
interface CustomType {
x: number,
y: number
}
```

and the the javascript code would resolve to
`object.method<CustomType>([...])`

My code:

```
interface CustomType {
  x: number,
  y: number
}

interface TypeMapper { 'CustomType': CustomType }

type Test = TypeMapper['CustomType'] // CustomType

function func<T>(x: number, y: number) {
  let v: T;
}
const typeVariable = 'CustomType';
const z = func<TypeMapper[typeVariable]>(1,2);
// 'typeVariable' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
// Did you mean 'typeof typeVariable'?(2749)
```

Comment: `interface TypeMapper { 'CustomType': CustomType}` like this?

Comment: yes something along those lines, however when i try to use that exact syntax I get an error that generally says: Error: type expected but found value

Comment: could you show the code you tried that didn't work then? An `interface` shouldn't say "found value"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen's solution works fine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZADwC5kR08AjaAGhrqOdYdoNAL40aoSLEQpiZALJwSZKMnLIA5Bmz45EDc225CpFGOo0wp5AQjZkAXhunFy6AG0tWY3o0BdZAB6QLRvXVMgA Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @AlexWayne I have modified the sandbox: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZADwC5kR08AjaAGhrqOdYdoNAL40aoSLEQpiZALJwSZKMnLIA5Bmz45EDc225CpFGOo0wp5AQjZkAXhunFy6AG0tWY3o0BdZAB6QLRvXVNxahh0EAQwYBwQZGjYgB4CAD4ACiYWNk4oLmR+PKEoAEo1XmQAGwgwZAA3ZgIAblEaBET7KzIANTgoYDh2OsdNI3CyDXbqLpB7AC9xlIR0lyUVd16IAaGRur9sgEYuACZy1qA) It should now show the error that i am encountering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error tells you how to fix it:

> 'typeVariable' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
> Did you mean 'typeof typeVariable'?(2749)

The type system can't act on values directly. You need to convert a value to the type of that value with the `typeof` keyword.

```
const typeVariable = 'CustomType';
type Z = TypeMapper[typeof typeVariable] // identical to: type Z = CustomType
```

And now if you hover over `func` on this line

```
const z = func<TypeMapper[typeof typeVariable]>(1,2);
```

It should tell you it is this type:

```
function func<CustomType>(x: number, y: number): void
```

Which seems to be what you are looking for.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZADwC5kR08AjaAGhrqOdYdoNAL40aoSLEQpiZALJwSZKMnLIA5Bmz45EDc225CpFGOo0wp5AQjZkAXhunFy6AG0tWY3o0BdZAB6QLRvXVNxahh0EAQwYBwQZGjYgB4CAD4ACiYWNk4oLmR+PKEoAEo1XmQAGwgwZAA3ZgJRGgRE+ysyADU4KGA4djrHTSNwsg0AbktrAC1RvVcVd26IHBhkNb6Bobq-ds6GgC9RlIR0lyUVtY2t0x3B4Yg-bIBGLgAmcqmgA)

---

> I am using a string variable that is not defined at compile time

Well that's a bit of a problem. Types *only* exist at compile time, so if you don't know it at compile time, then you have to manually test at runtime.

With this function:

```
function func1(type_string: string) {
  type t = TypeMapper[typeof type_string];
}
```

It's perfectly valid to pass in any `string`, since that's how the function is typed. So if you pass `"BadString"`, then what do you expect `t` to be?

To make this example work, you have to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type `string` to more specific types to know if the value is safe to use.

For example:

```
function func1(type_string: string) {
  if (type_string === 'CustomType') {
    type t = TypeMapper[typeof type_string]; // works
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Unknown type string: ${type_string}`)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZADwC5kR08AjaAGhrqOdYdoNAL40aoSLEQpiZALJwSZKMnLIA5Bmz45EDc225CpFGOo0wp5AQjZkAXhunFy6AG0tWY3o0BdZAB6QLRvXVNxahh0EAQwYBwQZGjYgB4CAD4ACiYWNk4oLmR+PKEoAEo1XmQAGwgwZAA3ZgJRGgRE+ysyADU4KGA4djrHTSNwsg0AbkiUuISkuYBGLO6IAH1sAZAAc2Yt0B3KqlpkYBhkVdNNsG2dxwcnLx0TSePqujXkBqc9VxV3GscBc1jc7n4pkEQgB3HBQADWmGqImQEBqmAoH2+AAsoDhoSwIASAKJQPFQLIAAwAqiB4SB8UkvgddswACTkUEsnYiSnlZGiIA)

There are a lot of ways to do narrowing, but it's hard to advise more on which to use from this very contrived code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the specific use case that I am using, I am using a string variable that is not defined at compile time, I have updated the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZADwC5kR08AjaAGhrqOdYdoNAL40aoSLEQpiZALJwSZKMnLIA5Bmz45EDc225CpFGOo0wp5AQjZkAXhunFy6AG0tWY3o0BdZAB6QLRvXVNxahh0EAQwYBwQZGjYgB4CAD4ACiYWNk4oLmR+PKEoAEo1XmQAGwgwZAA3ZgJRGgRE+ysyADU4KGA4djrHTSNwsg0AbktrAC1RvVcVd26IHBhkNb6Bobq-ds6GgC9RlIR0lyUVtY2t0x3B4Yg-bIBGLgAmcpmLKJi4gkkuc3lk1gB9bADEAAc2YUNAMPKNCotHuZC2iyubigq1MdwhCNhfl+IiAA)  Can you review this

Comment: I've updated my answer with more on that case.